# How Maven and Java handle duplicated dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I do have some random issues within my application. And I suspect that the problem may arise from external dependencies. Let me elaborate.

My application is using an external jar with requests classes. Inside one of my projects, I had added the newest version of this library. But as you probably suspect, I have more dependencies than just one. And unfortunately, one of these dependencies has the same library which I added already, but with an older version. So at this moment, when I am firing `mvn dependecy:tree`, simplified results look like that:

```
+-my_project
    +-request_lib.jar:1.5.0
    +-required_lib.jar:1.0.0
        +-random.jar:1.0.0
        +-request_lib.jar:1.2.0
        //more libs
    //more libs
```

As you can see, what I need is the newest version of `request_lib.jar:1.5.0`, and at this moment no one can update `required_lib.jar:1.0.0`, and change the version or request inside of it.

How does Java handle this situation? Lets say inside of this project I am using request `GetPlayerDataRequest`, and in the newest version someone added a new field to this called `String playerTitle`. Will Java always use classes from the newest version? Or will it be mixed?

Because from what I see, sometimes users have fatal errors, where in logs we can find that method `setPlayerData` does not exist. I know that I can exclude the old jar in the pom. But I would like to know how it is handled by Java.

Comment: You are asking about Maven and Java, but these are two separate issues. Java itself will happily allow (assuming you don't use the Java Module System) multiple libraries with the same packages and classes. It will simply load the classes from the first library it encounters on the classpath, and that order will depend on how the classpath was specified and composed. Maven on the other hand, will resolve to a single version of the library (assuming they both have the same groupId and artifactId and just differ in version) before that even comes into play. What part are you really interested in?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Maven's `<dependencyManagement>` feature.  This is one of the most misunderstood and [poorly documented](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) areas of Maven and yet also one of its most powerful features.

In your `pom.xml`, if you have a `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>` section, then **anything that is a child of it will apply *all the way down the dependency tree*, regardless of where else that dependency may be specified**.  (You can also include non-existing entries; if they designate a dependency that is not actually used anywhere by you or any of your transitive dependencies, then they are ignored.)

So, for example, if you want to ensure that the following dependency is used everywhere in your project no matter how it is "pulled in" or by whom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>32</version>
</dependency>
```

…then if you add that entry to your `pom.xml`'s `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>` section—even if your project itself doesn't use it, but your transitive dependencies do—so that it looks like this:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>

    <!-- other entries might go here -->

    <!-- force version 32 of com.foo:bar no matter how it gets pulled into your project -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      <version>32</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- other entries might go here -->

  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

…then that will do the trick.

A related thing that is not exactly documented anywhere is: dependency versions in "regular" `<dependencies>` entries (so `<dependency>` elements that do not appear as children of `<dependencyManagement><dependencies>` but only as children of `<dependencies>`) are *suggestions*.  They are used only if an overriding `<dependencyManagement>` entry does not exist (which many times, of course, it does not).

Answer (score 0):

Maven applies a dependency mediation mechanism, guaranteeing that only one of the two versions of the dependency gets bundled. So, in this case, Java doesn't have to handle anything really.

Relevant documentation: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Hmm, ok. I can undarstand that maven using the closest of jar during compile phase. But what about runtime? We are still have bundled multiple jar versions?

Comment: Only the jar chosen by Maven during the build will be available at runtime.

Comment: Your project requires dependency A v1.0 and dependency B. Dependency B in turn, requires a different version of dependency A (v2.0). Your project is compiled with the dependency A explicitly requested by you in the pom.xml, whereas dependency B **was** compiled before being published to Maven Central with the dependency A v2.0. Once you run your project, only the APIs from dependency A v1.0 are available and any breaking changes that there were between A v1.0 and v2.0 could cause runtime errors, precisely because B refers to A v2.0 but A v2.0 is not there. This is all there is to it.

Answer (score -2):

Java allows you to load different versions of the same class by using classloaders.

Using your example, you would load classes from request_lib.jar using one classloader, and required_lib.jar from another.

The topic is too extensive for a stackoverflow answer, there are many tutorials online.